# sqlalchemy, how to Base.metadata.drop_all with cascade?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest

I'm building setup and teardown for my pytest tests. I cannot drop tables because there are numerous dependiences between tables. Still, I need to drop all tables after each test.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def test_db():
    model.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=test_engine)
    db = TestSessionLocal()
    yield db
    model.Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=test_engine)
```

it throws me `psycopg2.errors.DependentObjectsStillExist`

I have also included cascades in my model but it does not work.

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    surname = Column(String)
    position = Column(String)
    skills = relationship("UserSkills", cascade="all, delete", passive_deletes=True)
    manager = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("manager.id", ondelete='CASCADE'))
    account_type = Column(Enum(AccountType), default=AccountType.USER)
    created = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

How can I add cascade option to `model.Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=test_engine)` ?

Answer (score 0):

To add cascade option to the metadata.drop_all(bind=engine) you need to specify this in each ForeignKey relation. The same is true for cascade onupdate.

Example from my project:

```
room_facility_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('hotel_room_facility.id', ondelete='CASCADE', onupdate='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
```